# Vi editor key customization

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, solaris, vi

Is there any way to customize the vi editor keys in Solaris Unix?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you find it too hard/alien to use, try a different editor. Changing the defaults will be a pain whenever you work on a vanilla solaris!

Answer (score 2):

Solaris uses `vi`; customization setting go in your `~/.exrc` file and are read on startup.

You can map editor keys with the map command (`:map <key> <command>`).  You can remap keys that are already used for other things, so be careful not to disable something you'll need.  Note that there are frequently other layers (e.g., X) that can map keys, so look out for conflict there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can remap keys using http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html

place these commands in you .vimrc or /etc/vim/vimrc to take effect everytime you use vim. (I hope this applies to solaris as well)

Comment: it applies to **vim**, but not necessarily **vi**.  vim is often but not always used as a replacement for vi.